# Passing a (local) variable to a generic method as Type

Tags: c#, generics

What I want to do, in very short version
Summary:

```
var localType = typeof(MyDTOClass);
var result = MyGenericMethod<localType>(string path);
```

VisualStudio is telling me that
dtoType is variable but is used like a type.

Long version:
I have the following dictionary, which is used to read some files from disk then using a (de)serializer convert it into objects. Contents of json files are almost identical so I am only putting one as example:
Json Contents,array of objects:

```
[{
"id": "1",
"areaType": "2",
"backgroundImagePath": "path",}, {
"id": "2",
"areaType": "2",
"backgroundImagePath": "path",}, {
"id": "99",
"areaType": "1",
"backgroundImagePath": "path",}]
```

Dictionary Contents:

```
var filesToParse = new Dictionary<string, Type>{
    { "area.json",typeof(AreaDto) },
    { "areaObject.json",typeof(AreaObjectDto) },
    { "monsterSymbol.json",typeof(MonsterSymbolDto) },
};
```

Code to retrieve contents of contents of json:

```
IEnumerable GetDeserializedJson(string pathToJsonFile, Type dtoType) {
    IEnumerable result;
    using (TextReader file = File.OpenText(pathToJsonFile)) {
    result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<IEnumerable<dtoType>>(file);
    }
    return result.OfType<dtoType>.Where(x => x != null);
}
```

My problem is with the following lines

```
result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<dtoType>(file);
result.OfType<dtoType>.Where(x => x != null);
```

dtoType is variable but is used like a type. I know it is a variable but it is a variable of Type. Can you please explain me why i cant pass this type variable and if possible how to further move with my problem.
The following is how I (want to) call my GetDeserializedJson

```
foreach(var keyValuePair in filesToParse){
    GetDeserializedJson<keyValuePair.Value>(keyValuePair.Key);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you make the `GetDeserializedJson` method generic as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: @EmrahSüngü, I think your problem is exactly the one in that link: you have a generic function that you want to call, but you have the type as a variable. If you cannot change the `GetDeserializedJson` method, maybe you could try the reflection approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide whether you'd like to use generics or types, but you can not 'switch' to generics on the fly.
Speaking of this example

```
var localType = typeof(MyDTOClass);
var result = MyGenericMethod<localType>(string path);
```

you just don't need first line, instead it should be

```
 var result = MyGenericMethod<MyDTOClass>(string path);
```

Speaking of other sample

```
IEnumerable GetDeserializedJson(string pathToJsonFile, Type dtoType) 
{
     IEnumerable result;
     using (TextReader file = File.OpenText(pathToJsonFile)) 
     {
          result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<IEnumerable<dtoType>>(file);
     }
     return result.OfType<dtoType>.Where(x => x != null);
}
```

You can declare generic method instead:

```
IEnumerable<TDto> GetDeserializedJson<TDto>(string pathToJsonFile) where TDto : DtoBaseClass
{
     IEnumerable<TDto> result;
     using (TextReader file = File.OpenText(pathToJsonFile)) 
     {
          result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader<IEnumerable<TDto>>(file);
     }
     return result.OfType<TDto>.Where(x => x != null);
}
```

In this way you don't even have to cast to your type and you have constraint `where TDto : DtoBaseClass` so compiler will not allow you use classes, not derived from you base dto class.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use nongeneric `DeserializeFromReader(reader, Type)` method, it will return you an `object`.
Something like this:

```
result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader(file, typeof(dtotype));
```

or if `dtoType` is instance of a `Type` then simply

```
result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromReader(file, dtotype);
```

Comment: Should the first one be without the `typeof` in there? dtoType in the OP's code is a `Type` so you probably don't want the typeof as standard (and you cover the situation where it isn't a type afterwards).

Comment: @Chris yep, you're right, but it's the second one. Thanks :)

Comment: @hazevich: Ah yes. Language gets very confusing when talking about whether a variables type is of type `Type` and such like.

Comment: @hazevich thank you very much for your comment. After I get my object how  can i proceed to cast it into`code <IEnumerable<dtoType>>`?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü to cast something, in this case I would say unbox type, you need actualy know type at compile time. I would have some class for each type, which will have some method with an argument of type object and it will know how to unbox it to it's actual type with an extra validation.